# Looking to identify book by Michael I. Jordan from excerpts

Tags: self-study, references

Michael I. Jordan lists 
[these readings](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~jordan/courses/260-spring10/other-readings/readings.html), which seem to be part of a larger book. I haven't been able to find out which, though. The bits that are available are great so I would really appreciate it if someone could tell me where to find the whole thing.

Comment: Pretty sure these are from a book he's writing, so you'll probably only be able to find other chapters by themselves.

Comment: I am also looking for this book. By reading Chapter 13 from the link [reading list](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~jordan/courses/260-spring10/other-readings/readings.html), I found something I need from it. Hope I can have some hint about what is this book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The chapters of the monograph that are being listed are from a draft book by Michael Jordan that to the best of my knowledge was never published, but continues to be used in many probabilistic graphical models courses.

The book is:

Jordan, M. I. (draft). *An Introduction to Probabilistic Graphical Models.*

A similar question was asked on quora at:

https://www.quora.com/Where-can-I-get-the-book-written-by-M-I-Jordan-Introduction-to-Graphical-Models-and-An-Introduction-to-Probabilistic-Graphical-Models

And a response was posted by Isaac Joseph supplying a link to all chapters of the book:

> A more complete copy than the below can be found here:
>
> [http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~lebanon/pub/book/](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Elebanon/pub/book/)

Answer (score 1):

I found a book on amazon that might cover these topics. It is "Graphical Models, Exponential Families and Variational Inference" (2008) by Wainwright and Jordan. There is also "Learning in Graphical Models (Adaptive Computation and Machine Learning)" (1998) MIT Press Michael I. Jordan editor.

Comment: Thank you Michael, but I just took a look at both and neither seems to be it. They don't fit the 2009 date given on his website either.

Comment: Amazon doesn't list any other books. If there were any after 2009 they would show up on Amazon.